# Complex URL rewriting with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Here is what i am trying to achieve

```
www.example.com/category
www.example.com/category/subcategory
www.example.com/category/subcategory/product
www.example.com/static-page (like /about-us, /contact, /our-services)
```

(category, subcategory, products, static-pages etc are dynamic text and there is a permalink foreach thing in the database)

if you see all above requests, you will notice that they are just like extending the directory sturcutre one step each time when the link is clicked, e.g, first was category, and then when I clicked on the subcatogery, I was sent to category/subcategory/ and the finally to product page

Anybody can help me how to acheive all this, i have tried lot to achieve this but in vain yet. 
Currently i am using this .htaccess

```
RewriteRule c/(.*)/(.*)/ cat-details.php?permalink=$1&subcat=$2
RewriteRule c/(.*)/(.*) cat-details.php?permalink=$1&subcat=$2

RewriteRule news/(.*)/(.*)/ news-detail.php?news-id=$1&permalink=$2
RewriteRule news/(.*)/(.*) news-detail.php?news-id=$1&permalink=$2

RewriteRule d/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ download-detail.php?download-id=$1category=$2&subcategory=$3&permalink=$4
RewriteRule d/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) download-detail.php?download-id=$1category=$2&subcategory=$3&permalink=$4
```

As you can see i have to add c/, news/, d/ etc for each link, i am trying to get rid of this and want to make links pretty whitout proceeding c/, news/, d/ etc

Comment: If you don't have `/c` or `/news` prefix how will Apache know which script to load for URI `/foo/bar`? Should it be `/cat-details.php?permalink=fo&subcat=bar` OR `/news-details.php?permalink=fo&subcat=bar` ?

Comment: Yes thats exactly i want to create links without prefix. exactly like<br/>

  http://www.romulation.net/roms/  
  http://www.romulation.net/roms/NDS/  
  http://www.romulation.net/roms/NDS/6222-3-in-1-Horses-E-M3-QueLLBRUNN.rar/

Answer (score 0):

About the only way you're going to be able to do this in Apache proper, is to provide info on which URLs map to which scripts.  Apache lets you do this via the `RewriteMap` directive, but that won't work in .htaccess files.  Without it, and without the `news/` or `c/`, Apache doesn't have enough info to route the URLs properly.

What you could do, is simply rewrite every URL that doesn't refer to an existing file, to a script that knows which scripts to run in response.   A "router" or "front controller" script, they call it.  Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)   router.php?path=$1  [QSA]
```

And in the script, you examine `$_GET['path']`, decide which script should handle the request, and load/include/require it.

Comment: what about some like  
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /romuniverse/download-detail.php?download-id=$1&category=$2&subcategory=$3&permalink=$4 [L]

Comment: @AngelaTaylor: You could do something like that; it'd rewrite every URL with 4 parts to `/romuniverse/download-detail.php`.  You couldn't do the same thing with `c/` and `news/`, cause they both look the same if you strip off the prefix.  You'd need some way to disambiguate.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way myself, just posting it if it could help anyone else in trouble just like me :p

```
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /romuniverse/cat.php?permalink=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /romuniverse/sub-cat.php?permalink=$1&subcat=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.rar$ /romuniverse/download-detail.php?download-id=$1&category=$2&subcategory=$3&permalink=$4 [L]
```